# s3cmd Put file with spaces on their names

Tags: s3cmd

I´m getting a problem to put or sync files to a bucket with spaces on their names.

The program freezes, no error messages are showed or logged.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem syncing files that had spaces in their names several years ago.  This was fixed with

```
commit fdfe03a57d20a1064f04282ee7bc3656041df918
Author: Michal Ludvig <mludvig@logix.net.nz>
Date:   Sun Nov 16 09:38:51 2008 +0000
Merge from 0.9.8.x branch, rel 245:
* S3/S3.py: Escape parameters in strings. Fixes sync to and
  ls of directories with spaces. (Thx Lubomir Rintel from Fedora Project)
```

You might try using the https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd master branch and try reproducing the problem with that version.  The testsuite within master branch syncs files with spaces in their names as part of standard testing practices, so this is known to work with recent code.